# iOS8 scrolling position:fixed element when interacting with a <select>

Tags: css, forms, ios8

When I am on iOS8 (this doesn't happen in iOS7, or anywhere else) and I interact with a  inside a fixed position modal window, the modal element jumps up and down. Sometimes it stays a significant distance below. When I inspect the element, the inspector thinks the element is in the correct position, however the content is below.

Attached screenshots showing the strange behaviour:

> Before select interaction:
>   [image: Before select]
>   After select interaction:
>   ![image]

My dom structure is as follows:

```
> Body ~ 3000+pixels high
>> Overlay (position: fixed) ~ 100% viewport high
>> Modal window (position: fixed) ~ 400px high, 50% top, -200px margin top
>>> Form with <select>
```

Comment: what if to change it to position absolute?

Comment: @sdcr changing its position to absolute stops the problem - but it has to be fixed for several reasons.